# Java Graphics2D getPixelBounds or getStringWidth not useful with drawString

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to place two words at the center of the image. But the drawString method does not seem to correctly pickup the "x" coodinate. For example I am trying to place the words "setupa" and "asetup" (image width 30). My image width is 106, thus the x-cord value is 38 in both the cases. But in reality asetup is places at 1-2 pixel shift.

It produces just minor difference, but that shows up in my images.

Sample code is follows.

```
    Graphics2D textGraphics;
    textGraphics = image.createGraphics();
    textGraphics.setColor(fontColor);

    textGraphics.setFont(font);
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

    TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(label, font, frc);
    Rectangle r = layout.getPixelBounds(frc, 0, 0);
    textGraphics.drawString(label, ((imageWidth / 2) - (r.width/2)), (imageWidth / 2));
```

Is they any way around this? or a better way to place the text at the center.

Thanks

Comment: How do you draw more strings onto the image? I see only one line in the example code you've given. If the strings all use the same TextLayout, then that could be your issue.

Comment: The sample code was part of a function. I actually figured out the problem. 

Each font used has its own way of representation of characters. For e.g. I am using Arial font for which "a" is shifted by one pixel to right. While "s" exactly starts from the 0-pixel mark. So when I am trying to center align the text "asetup", it appears shifted and the word "setupa" does not.
Textlayout bounds for both are the same which is correct.

But still i do not know to resolve it.